# dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "JNI_OnLoad_javajpeg"

Tags: android, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, graalvm-native-image

I have pretty simple desktop app written in JavaFX. The only task is to get a search term (text input box), send a request to my REST API and display results in a form of articles list (name and photo).
When I try to convert this app to native Android app using Gluon, there is an error that I can't figure out how to fix.

---

**The question is: How to fix this error and run my app on Android device?**

---

Tools (software) I use are:
`Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`,
`Java 17`,
`graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final`,
`Maven 3.8.8`,
`android-ndk-r25c`.

**EDIT:** Tried with `Java 11` and there is no difference.

---

Steps I do:

```
$ mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build
$ mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:package
$ mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:install
$ mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:nativerun
```

Last step is not working because I get an error:

```
[INFO] [SUB] --------- beginning of crash
[INFO] [SUB] E/AndroidRuntime(28624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[INFO] [SUB] E/AndroidRuntime(28624): Process: com.thevegcat.TheVegCatApp, PID: 28624
[INFO] [SUB] E/AndroidRuntime(28624): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "JNI_OnLoad_javajpeg" referenced by "/data/app/~~MsvDADBiJ40PbJ6YgoWjVw==/com.thevegcat.TheVegCatApp-jeiDsmOewudHMN1dhopxxA==/lib/arm64/libsubstrate.so"...
[INFO] [SUB] E/AndroidRuntime(28624):   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)
[INFO] [SUB] E/AndroidRuntime(28624):   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)
[INFO] [SUB] E/AndroidRuntime(28624):   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1656)
[INFO] [SUB] E/AndroidRuntime(28624):   at com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity.surfaceCreated(MainActivity.java:107)
```

---

Workaround that can create fake symbols (without real implementations):
https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-javafx-game-mobile-graalvm

After *fixing* already mentioned first symbol, new symbols show up and finally when I *fix* them all, app starts, but it shows only black blank screen. When I tap device's screen, I get response in debug log which tells me it's working, but not as expected because all those missing symbols were about graphics which are now not available (empty methods without implementations created by this dirty fix).

---

**EDIT:** Found that I'm not the only one:
https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/pull/1000

---

**EDIT:** Method to be referenced in comments below

```
private Image fetchImage(final String photo) {
    final String imageUrl = this.host + photo;
    try {
        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageUrl));
        return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**pom.xml**

```
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>The Vegan Catalog App</name>
  <description>The Best World Vegan Catalog by H.Lo</description>

  <groupId>com.thevegcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>TheVegCatApp</artifactId>

  <version>1.0.2</version>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>HLo</id>
      <name>Hrvoje Lončar</name>
      <email>horvoje@gmail.com</email>
    </developer>
  </developers>

  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <main.class>com.thevegcat.app.TheVegCatApp</main.class>
    <launcher.class>com.thevegcat.app.Launcher</launcher.class>

                  <javafx.LTS.version>17.0.7</javafx.LTS.version>
                 <httpclient5.version>5.2.1</httpclient5.version>
               <jersey-client.version>3.1.2</jersey-client.version>
       <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
          <maven-shade-plugin.version>3.4.1</maven-shade-plugin.version>
            <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
       <maven-assembly-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
           <jakarta.ws.rs-api.version>3.1.0</jakarta.ws.rs-api.version>
      <jakarta.activation-api.version>2.1.2</jakarta.activation-api.version>
                      <lombok.version>1.18.28</lombok.version>
         <javafx-maven-plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx-maven-plugin.version>
                <webp-imageio.version>0.1.6</webp-imageio.version>
               <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>

<!-- BEGIN Android attempt -->

               <charm-glisten.version>6.2.3</charm-glisten.version>
                     <connect.version>2.0.1</connect.version>
                      <attach.version>4.0.18</attach.version>
              <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.18</gluonfx.plugin.version>

<!-- END Android attempt -->

  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- BEGIN Android attempt -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.LTS.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.LTS.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.6</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
      <artifactId>display</artifactId>
      <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
      <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
      <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
      <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
      <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
      <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
      <artifactId>device</artifactId>
      <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
      <artifactId>push-notifications</artifactId>
      <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
      <artifactId>runtime-args</artifactId>
      <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
      <artifactId>util</artifactId>
      <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- END Android attempt -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.LTS.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.LTS.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.LTS.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.LTS.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jakarta.ws.rs-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jakarta.activation-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
      <version>${httpclient5.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey-client.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey-client.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey-client.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.sejda.imageio</groupId>
      <artifactId>webp-imageio</artifactId>
      <version>${webp-imageio.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>${java.version}</release>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <shadedClassifierName>project-classifier</shadedClassifierName>
              <outputFile>shade\TheVegCatApp.jar</outputFile>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation=
                  "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>${launcher.class}</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

<!-- BEGIN Android attempt -->

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.31</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
          <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
          <attachList>
            <list>display</list>
            <list>lifecycle</list>
            <list>statusbar</list>
            <list>storage</list>
            <list>device</list>
            <list>push-notifications</list>
            <list>runtime-args</list>
          </attachList>
          <reflectionList>
            <list>com.thevegcat.sample.User</list>
          </reflectionList>

          <!-- ugly fix for 'cannot locate symbol {} referenced by {}'
            caused by bad linking that is made by gluon or graalvm -->
          <!--
          <linkerArgs>
            <arg>android/missing_symbols.o</arg>
          </linkerArgs>
          -->

        </configuration>
      </plugin>

<!-- END Android attempt -->

    </plugins>

  </build>

<!-- BEGIN Android attempt -->

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>android</id>
      <properties>
        <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>ios</id>
      <properties>
        <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

<!-- END Android attempt -->

</project>
```

Comment: That error (missing `JNI_OnLoad_javajpeg`) comes from some AWT dependency (probably from `org.sejda.imageio:webp-imageio`), that makes use of the `javajpeg` library from the JDK. This could work on Linux, but not on Android. Can you remove it or comment it out for now (and all the related code) and try again?

Comment: @JoséPereda So far I removed dependency  `org.sejda.imageio:webp-imageio` and made :build, :package, :install and :nativerun - but the same error shows up.

Comment: Then check where do you use AWT. You should also remove Swing dependency.

Comment: @JoséPereda Next thing I did - edited my question and added code block with method that could be the source of problem - it uses `SwingFXUtils.toFXImage`.

Comment: Well, that's weird now. I removed `org.openjfx:javafx-swing' from dependencies and replaced the body of method that uses it with `return null;` and the error still shows.

Comment: Also removed `org.openjfx:javafx-graphics` and still the same error. No further ideas on my side.

Comment: If you have removed all swing dependencies you shouldn’t see the same error, so make sure you clean and build the project properly before deploying to your Android device.

Comment: @JoséPereda Today I tried again. After each dependency removal I manually emptied target directory by `rm -rf *` and then checked is it really empty with `ls -al` and it was empty. And the same thing happens. The next thing I can think of is to start with hello world app and add dependencies one by one and after each add run the whole process. I mean it will take a week, but maybe it's the only way to find out which dependency causes the mess.

Comment: You can try that of course. Make sure in any case that the app you are testing is the new one (uninstall also from your device). Then you can try this: unzip the resulting apk and run from a terminal `nm lib/arm64-v8a/libsubstrate.so | grep javajpeg`, see if there is any entry (post the result if that is the case)?